# How to get the pivotTable options and uncheck the "show the Values row" in display tab using Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

if there are multiple dataFields, then there is a additional field named Values in pivot table's GUI view of excel.
So how to hide "values" field using Apache POI in java
Please help me out in resolving it.

Answer (score 2):

The "Show the Values row" setting for pivot tables was implemented after the `Office Open XML` was published. That's why it is not part of it. It uses special extended XML from name space `x14`. But `apache poi`only provides `Office Open XML`.

So if we want using extended XML from name space `x14`, we need doing that on low XML level.

First we need setting updated pivot table version to 6 instead of 3.

```
...
XSSFPivotTable pivotTable...
...
pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().setUpdatedVersion((short)6); 
...
```

Then we need set `<x14:pivotTableDefinition hideValuesRow="1"/>` for CTPivotTableDefinition. This is the "Show the Values row" setting.

```
...
org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTExtensionList extList = pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().addNewExtLst();
org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTExtension ext = extList.addNewExt();
String extXML = 
   "<x14:pivotTableDefinition"
 + " xmlns:x14=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2009/9/main\""
 + " hideValuesRow=\"1\"/>";
org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject xlmObject = org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject.Factory.parse(extXML);
ext.set(xlmObject);
ext.setUri("{962EF5D1-5CA2-4c93-8EF4-DBF5C05439D2}");
...
```

Complete example:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;

class CreatePivotTableHideValuesRow {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  try (Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); 
       FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream("Excel.xlsx") ) {

   Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();

   String[] headers = new String[]{"Column1", "Column2", "Count"};
   Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
   Cell cell;
   for (int c = 0; c < headers.length; c++) {
    cell = row.createCell(c); cell.setCellValue(headers[c]);
   }

   Object[][] data = new Object[][]{
    new Object[]{"A", "Aa", 2d},
    new Object[]{"A", "Aa", 4d},
    new Object[]{"A", "Ab", 1d},
    new Object[]{"A", "Ac", 7d},
    new Object[]{"B", "Ba", 5d},
    new Object[]{"B", "Bb", 5d},
    new Object[]{"B", "Bb", 2d},
    new Object[]{"B", "Bc", 8d}
   };
   for (int r = 0; r < data.length; r++) {
    row = sheet.createRow(r+1);
    Object[] rowData = data[r];
    for (int c = 0; c < rowData.length; c++) {
     cell = row.createCell(c);
     if (rowData[c] instanceof String) {
      cell.setCellValue((String)rowData[c]);
     } else if (rowData[c] instanceof Double) {
      cell.setCellValue((Double)rowData[c]);
     }
    }
   }

   XSSFPivotTable pivotTable = ((XSSFSheet)sheet).createPivotTable(
    new AreaReference("A1:C9", SpreadsheetVersion.EXCEL2007),
    new CellReference("E4")
   );

   pivotTable.addRowLabel(0);
   pivotTable.addRowLabel(1);

   // the default sets data on columns and data fields as col fields
   pivotTable.addColumnLabel(DataConsolidateFunction.SUM, 2);
   pivotTable.addColumnLabel(DataConsolidateFunction.AVERAGE, 2);

   //set updated pivot table version to 6
   //necessary to make extended pivot table setting available
   pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().setUpdatedVersion((short)6); 

   //set <x14:pivotTableDefinition hideValuesRow="1"/> for CTPivotTableDefinition
   //this is the "Show the Values row" setting
   org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTExtensionList extList = pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().addNewExtLst();
   org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTExtension ext = extList.addNewExt();
   String extXML = 
      "<x14:pivotTableDefinition"
    + " xmlns:x14=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2009/9/main\""
    + " hideValuesRow=\"1\"/>";
   org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject xlmObject = org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject.Factory.parse(extXML);
   ext.set(xlmObject);
   ext.setUri("{962EF5D1-5CA2-4c93-8EF4-DBF5C05439D2}");

   workbook.write(fileout);

  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

<poi.version>3.16</poi.version> and <poi.version>4.1.2</poi.version>
class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTExtensionList no exists((

solution: for poi.version 3.16 add dependency

```
<dependency>            
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>           
    <artifactId>ooxml-schemas</artifactId>          
    <version>1.3</version>      
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

`CTPivotTableDefinition pivotDefinition = pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition(); pivotDefinition.setRowGrandTotals(false); pivotTable.setCTPivotTableDefinition(pivotDefinition);`